# Null "Page" Parameter Error When Called From Controller, Using JQGrid in MVC 4 Web Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I'm trying to implement a JQGrid that takes information from my controller, following the approach in this tutorial, http://haacked.com/archive/2009/04/13/using-jquery-grid-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx.

The code for my controller is:

```
    public ActionResult GridData(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
    {
        var jsonData = new
        {
            total = 1,  
            page = page,
            records = 1, 
            rows = new[]
            {
                new {id = 1, cell = new[] {"", "", "", "", "", "", "f", "", "", "", "",     "", "", ""}},
            }
        };
        return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The code for my View is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-    1.8.23.custom.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/ui.multiselect.css" />

<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function ()
{
    jQuery("#list").jqGrid(
        {
            url: '/WebFormUserList/GridData',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'GET',
            colNames:
                [
                    'User_ID', 'Forename', 'Surname', 'Client_Code', 'User_Name',
                    'Password', 'Email', 'Gender', 'Report_Date', 'Email_Date',
                    'Test_Count', 'Test_Completed', 'Job_Function', 'Lookup_Value'
                ],
            colModel:
                [
                    { name: 'User_ID', index: 'User_ID', width: 'auto', align: 'centre' },
                    { name: 'Forename', index: 'Forename', width: 'auto', align: 'centre' },
                    { name: 'Surname', index: 'Surname', width: 'auto', align: 'centre' },
                    { name: 'Client_Code', index: 'Client_Code', width: 'auto', align: 'centre' },
                    { name: 'User_Name', index: 'User_Name', width: 'auto', align: 'centre' },
                    { name: 'Password', index: 'Password', width: 'auto', align: 'centre' },
                    { name: 'Email', index: 'Email', width: 'auto', align: 'centre' },
                    { name: 'Gender', index: 'Gender', width: 'auto', align: 'centre' },
                    { name: 'Report_Date', index: 'Report_Date', width: 'auto', align: 'centre' },
                    { name: 'Email_Date', index: 'Email_Date', width: 'auto', align: 'centre' },
                    { name: 'Test_Count', index: 'Test_Count', width: 'auto', align: 'centre' },
                    { name: 'Test_Completed', index: 'Test_Completed', width: 'auto', align: 'centre' },
                    { name: 'Job_Function', index: 'Job_Function', width: 'auto', align: 'centre' },
                    { name: 'Lookup_Value', index: 'Lookup_Value', width: 'auto', align: 'centre' },
                ],

            pager: jQuery('#pager'),
            height: 'auto',
            width: 1000,
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
            sortname: 'Id',
            sortorder: "desc",
            viewrecords: true,
            imgpath: '/css/ui-lightness/images',
            caption: 'My first grid'
        });
});
```

When I try to call the page for the grid, I get the error below.

The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'page' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult GridData(System.String, System.String, Int32, Int32)' in 'HFI_Assessment_Administration.Controllers.WebFormUserListController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

I would greatly appreciate any help or advice people could offer. If someone could also explain how sidx, sord, page, rows are passed, that would also greatly help my understanding.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`page` is not initialized in your example.
try this:

```
        page  = 1,
        records = 1, 
        rows = new[]
        {
            new {id = 1, cell = new[] {"", "", "", "", "", "", "f", "", "", "", "",     "", "", ""}},
        }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. If I change my code to remove page and rows, my View returns this. {"total":1,"page":1,"records":1,"rows":[{"id":1,"cell":["","","","","","","f","","","","","","",""]}]}. Now I'm really confused.